# Referencing a dynamic variable?

Tags: php

```
for ($count = 1; $count <= 5; ++$count) {
  $test = ${'node->field_aw_score_' . $count}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  echo $test;
}
```

Throws the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: node->field_aw_score_1
Notice: Undefined variable: node->field_aw_score_2
Notice: Undefined variable: node->field_aw_score_3
Notice: Undefined variable: node->field_aw_score_4
Notice: Undefined variable: node->field_aw_score_5
```

However, the variables do exist. I'm trying to reference:

```
$node->field_aw_score_1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']
```

then

```
$node->field_aw_score_2[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']
```

etc. A dynamic variable. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Use `$count++` instead of `++$count`

Comment: `$node->{'field_aw_score_' . $count}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']`

Comment: @hek2mgl I havent seen like this before, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$node->{'field_aw_score_' . $count}
```